# Can not load webservice with SOAP in PHP, I get SOAP-ERROR

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a web service that I want to access through SOAP. 
But I get a SOAP-ERROR:

```
Exception caught: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn´t load from 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/info?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1:9999/info?wsdl"
```

If I manually enter the URL http://127.0.0.1:9999/info?wsdl in the browser, then I can see the generated xml file.

Why can´t I load it with SOAP?

I load the URL with SOAP in PHP like this:

> $soap = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1:9999/info?wsdl",
>   array("trace" => TRUE));

What have I missed?

**EDIT**
Setting SOAP version to 1.1 does NOT make it working:

```
$soap = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1:9999/info?wsdl", array("trace" => TRUE, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have got it working on both Windows and on Ubuntu, but not on CentOS 6. Is it something with CentOS 6 that makes PHP:s SoapClient not working? The PHP version I am running on the CentOS 6 machine is 5.3.3 with (of course) Soap support enabled in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your answers and ideas! But we have found the problem. It was stuff in SELinux that had to be disabled (you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and edit the line `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive` (or `SELINUX=disabled`  to disable SELinux). 
Also, in our case,  we had to run the php files that connects to the WSDL as root (`chown root /path/to/phpfile/on/webserver/file.php`).
 We had this problem only when using CentOS 6, not when using Ubuntu och MS Windows. 

Also, have a look at @dar7yl:s link: http://www.victorstanciu.ro/php-soapclient-port-bug-workaround/ if you cannot solve the problem with the changes in SELinux and running the php file as root.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and this too cured my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem.  Basically, the current version of the SOAP Client doesn't handle *REMOTE* wsdl's (even if the remote server is "localhost") properly... don't know why, tried many ways to get working, just doesn't.   If you download a copy of the wsdl and save it locally an use it like:

```
$soap = new SoapClient("/path/to/local/file.wsdl");
```

It works like a charm.

If you really need a live wsdl your options are:

- Find an older version of the NuSoap and use it
- Use something like the php curl library to pull the wsdl down and save it as a local file, then create your Soap Client object from this newly saved file.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the PHP Soap library can't handle WDSL version 2.  You might have to look for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: In the SOAP constructor I added "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1 but it didn´t help. :( Have a look at my edit above.

Comment: The PHP documention says that PHP has support for version 2: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Oh, you wrote WSDL 2.0, not SOAP 2.0. Is it possible to set the version to WSDL 1.0?

Comment: not sure.  I gave up on calling the web services directly from php, and wrote a little glue program in C# (I'm working on a WAMP server) that gets called via system().  It's crude and inefficient, but it works for me.  You might look at http://www.victorstanciu.ro/php-soapclient-port-bug-workaround/ to see if that's your problem.  (It may have been mine as well; I couldn't afford the project downtime then to analyze the problem)

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with SELinux enforcing.

Since httpd scripts by default are not allowed to connect out to the network, if you need scripts to be able to connect you can set the httpd_can_network_connect boolean on.

Comment: Command to do that is: sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on